# Does strcmp(s1,s2) compare only first non equal character value of s1 and s2?

Tags: c, string

I am not convinced by the definition of `strcmp()`, it says it will compare entire strings (the two strings passed in as parameters, and returns `-1`, `0`, `1` based on `s1<s2`, `s1` (same as) `s2`, `s1>s2`.

If so, how do you justify below snippet from K&R, after very first non-equal character encounter, you exit out of loop. How are we comparing all characters of `s1` and `s2` until end (`'\0'`) ?

```
char *p1 = &str1[0], *p2 = &str2[0];

while (1) {
    if (*p1 != *p2)
        return *p1 - *p2;
    if (*p1 == '\0' || *p2 == '\0')
        return 0;
    p1++;
    p2++;
}
```

Comment: Where did your description come from? There is no need, sense, or purpose to keep on comparing after you find a difference.

Comment: [http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strncmp.html](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strncmp.html)

Comment: @Jongware, my understanding was str1 = "Aasdasdasd" is greater than str2 = "a", which is not true as per strcmp() , so we just discard other characters of Str1? is that right? why not count ASCII value of other characters as well for final sum and then decide who is greater.

Comment: Because that's not what it does.. if you want a function that adds up all the character ASCII values then make one and call it davids_strtotalsumcmp() or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`strcmp()` will halt as soon as the first non-equal character is found, since that's enough to determine lexicographic order of any two words.

This is the norm for "classic" `strcmp()` (1)

It follows that by carefully timing the result of a `strcmp()` of a *known* string against an *unknown* string (e.g. a *password*), one might be able to determine which character actually failed the comparison, which would then allow to guess any character using at most 25*N (or 255*N if you use the whole ASCII set, excluding zero) attempts. This is known as a [timing attack](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/13512/constant-time-string-comparision-in-php-to-prevent-timing-attacks).

So there *are* also implementations of `secure strcmp()` which have the property of requiring a time proportional to the length of the first string being supplied. You might conceivably have encountered a reference to such.

---

(1) other text-comparing functions exist that may handle things differently, e.g. with wide and multibyte characters, where sometimes it may be desirable for two different characters to compare the same - say, "a" and "à"; yet it could be argued that we're no longer speaking about simple *comparison* but about the more complex [*collation*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_collation_algorithm)).

Comment: `strcmp` compares bytes, not wide or multibyte characters, so the latter are irrelevant. However unless your multibyte encoding is insane, `strcmp` will also do something reasonable for multibyte strings too (for instance with UTF-8 it gives codepoint order).

Comment: Yes, sorry. I was referring to the wider gamut of string-comparing functions. Editing the answer.

Answer (score 0):

`strcmp` performs classic lexicographical comparison of two strings. The result of lexicographical comparison is already immediately known the very moment you find the first non-matching character. That's exactly what you see in the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Most implementations of `strcmp()` return as soon as a character is different in both strings. Hence it does not always *compare the whole strings*, because it is only necessary for identical strings.

Note that `strcmp()` does not necessarily return `-1` nor `1` if the strings differ... only the sign of the return value is relevant to determine whether `s1` is lexicographically lesser or greater than `s2`.

Also worth mentioning is the fact that comparison of `char` elements is performed on their value converted to `(unsigned char)`, making the result independent of the compiler setting for `char` signedness.  The same is true for `memcmp`.

Here is a sample (and simple) implementation for architectures with `sizeof(char) < sizeof(int)`:

```
int strcmp(const char *s1, const char *s2) {
    while (*s1 == *s2 && *s1 != '\0') {
        s1++;
        s2++;
    }
    return (unsigned char)*s1 - (unsigned char)*s2;
}
```